# How do I align 4 different size divs in a box shape, so that green one can be put in the corner

Tags: html, css

How do I align these divs so the **green** one goes to the left corner between **red** and **yellow** divs?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head><link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
    <body>
        <div id='red'></div>
        <div id='blue'></div>
        <div id='yellow'></div>
        <div id='green'></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

```css
#red
{ 
    background-color: red;
    height:500px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#blue
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    width:75%;
    float: left;
}

#green
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#yellow
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height:650px;
    width:75%;
    float: left;
}
```

[image: Reference Image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use `float: right;` for your blue and yellow `div` :

```css
#red
{ 
    background-color: red;
    height:500px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#blue
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    width:75%;
    float: right;
}

#green
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#yellow
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height:650px;
    width:75%;
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="red"></div>
<div id="blue"></div>
<div id="yellow"></div>
<div id="green"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the green one in the corner just specify the alignment positions for each div.This would bring the green to the left most corner.Specify the correct alignment for each colors.I have provided the code for your reference

```html
<style>
#red
{ 
    background-color: red;
    height:500px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#blue
{
    background-color: blue;
    height: 150px;
    width:75%;
    float: right;
}

#green
{
    background-color: green;
    height: 300px;
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
}

#yellow
{
    background-color: yellow;
    height:650px;
    width:75%;
    float: right;
}
</style>
 <head>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></head>
<body>
    <div id='red'></div>
    <div id='blue'></div>
    <div id='yellow'></div>
    <div id='green'></div>
</body>
```